# Does Datalab (Google Cloud) continue to run the code after I close the tab?

Tags: google-cloud-datalab

[From this issue](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/1647), I understand that the datalab will not print anything to the notebook client-side, but will the code still execute?

I've created a for loop, which is very very long.

```
a = np.array()
for i in range(HUGE):
    np.append(a,i)
a.dump('a')
```

When the cell completes, the variable `a` is saved to disk, so that I can continue working with it tomorrow.

My worry is that if I close the datalab tab, it will stop executing. It's already been ~7 hours, I calculated the loop to take around 9 hours.

Comment: I'd suggest you'd better use a VM instance and schedule a job via `linux` command tools (or if you prefer - `ML Engine`). Datalab is not the best place to run such computations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a `Datalab` specific situation. `Datalab` uses an underlying `ipython` kernel to execute the code you send through the notebook cells, so once you do `shift+Enter` or click the Run button, the code starts running on the notebook server, and it keeps running even if you close the browser. Keep in mind that, as far as I understand, consecutive cells will *not* be sent for execution if you've closed the browser tab, since the sending part is done by the client code in the browser. In other words, only the cell that managed to start running before you exited will continue running. If your code that dumps the results is in a following cell, move it to the same cell.

Comment: This is not quite true. You are right with respect to the browser tabs. However, if you lose connection from the datalab client to the cloud, like say your computer falls asleep, or your internet goes down, Google shuts down the entire VM hosting your server. The code doesn't finish, because the virtual computer it was running on ceases to exist, or at least be turned on, depending on how you interpret existence.

Comment: Google will not stop the VM, unless you have auto-shutdown set up in Datalab, or you stop it manually. See https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/concepts/auto-shutdown